# Regex match a string with spaces (use quotes?) in an if statement

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, debian

How would I do a regex match as shown below but with quotes around the ("^This") as in the real world "This" will be a string that can have spaces in it.

```
#!/bin/bash

text="This is just a test string"
if [[ "$text" =~ ^This ]]; then
 echo "matched"

else
 echo "not matched"
fi
```

I want to do something like

```
    if [[ "$text" =~ "^This is" ]]; then
```

but this doesn't match.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `\` before spaces.

```
#!/bin/bash

text="This is just a test string"
if [[ "$text" =~ ^This\ is\ just ]]; then
  echo "matched"
else
  echo "not matched"
fi
```

Comment: +1 This is definitely the way to do it. Bash regexes used with `=~` should most often (always?) be unquoted.

Comment: That's good to hear. I've never used bash regexes before, I just experimented and found that \ worked. *On S.O., it's correct until proven wrong!*

Comment: FWIW, this changed between Bash 3.1 and Bash 3.2.  Bash 4.0 has a configurable `shopt -s/-u compat31` to toggle between the behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to inline the expression like this:

```
if [[ "$text" =~ "^ *This " ]]; then
```

but if you put the expression in a variable you could use normal regex syntax like this:

```
pat="^ *This "
if [[ $text =~ $pat ]]; then
```

Note that the quoting on `$text` and `$pat` is unnessesary.

**Edit:**
A convinient oneliner during the development:

```
pat="^ *This is "; [[ "   This is just a test string" =~ $pat ]]; echo $?
```

Comment: The are no spaces at the beginning of `$text` so `$pat` should be `"^This"`. Also, quoting the variables here is not only unnecessary, it won't work. +1 for showing the variable format.

Answer (score -1):

can you make your problem description clearer?

```
text="This is just a test string"
case "$text" in
    "This is"*) echo "match";;
esac
```

the above assume you want to match "This is" at exactly start of line.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried:

```
^[\s]*This
```