# List file using ls with a condition and process/grep files that only whitespaces

Tags: bash, ls

I have a list of files in a folder which some of the files have spaces in the filename. 
I need to replace the whitespace with _  but first, i need to list the file with condition `ls *_[1-4]*[A-c]*` . After filter the files, some of the files have whitespace with no fixed position(front, middle, end position).
How can i replace the whitespace after ls command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [don't want to process the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Simply loop over the matching files.

```
for file in *_[1-4]*[A-c]*; do
    # Skip files which do not contain any whitespace
    case $file in *\ *) ;; *) continue;; esac
    echo mv -n "$file" "${file// /_}"
done
```

The `echo` is there as a safeguard; take it out if the output looks correct.

The `case` and the substitution looks for a space (ASCII 32); if you also want to match tabs, form feeds, etc, adapt accordingly.  `bash` allows for something like `$[\t ]` to match a tab or space, but this is not portable to other Bourne shell implementations

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to actually rename the files.

Comment: That's how I interpreted *"I need to replace the whitespace with `_`"*

Comment: hi...just curious.. instead using case , can i using if statement? if can, what it shoul be like?

Comment: Sure you can, but I would recommend you to embrace the `case` statement.  The syntax looks weird but you get used to it quickly.

Comment: See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599103/regex-match-a-string-with-spaces-use-quotes-in-an-if-statement

Comment: i changed to if statement but no results come out. im using `if [[ "$file" =~ "*\ *" ]]; then` , is this the correct one after convert to if statement?

Comment: It also depends on your Bash version. But no, that is an unholy mix of glob and regex which cannot work. If you use `=~` you need to use regular expressions, not glob patterns. I can only reemphasize that this is one of the many reasons I prefer `case`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `find` to list the files and pipe to the results to `sed`:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*_[1-4]*[A-c]*' | sed 's/ /_/g'
```