# List file using ls to find meet the condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a batch program to delete all file in a directory with condition in filename.

In the directory there's a large number of text file (~ hundreds of thousand of files) with filename fixed as "abc" + date

```
abc_20180820.txt
abc_20180821.txt
abc_20180822.txt
abc_20180823.txt
abc_20180824.txt
```

The program try to grep all the file, compare the date to a fixed-date, delete it if filename's date < fixed date.
But the problem is it took so long to handle that large amount of file (~1 hour to delete 300k files).

My question: Is there a way to compare the date when running ls command? Not get all file in a list then compare to delete, but list only file already meet the condition then delete. I think that will have better performance.

My code is

```
   TARGET_DATE =  "5-12"
    DEL_DATE = "20180823"   
    ls -t |  grep "[0-9]\{8\}".txt\$ > ${LIST}
        for EACH_FILE in  `cat ${LIST}` ;
        do
            DATE=`echo ${EACH_FILE} | cut -c${TARGET_DATE }`
            COMPARE=`expr "${DATE}" \< "${DEL_DATE}"`
            if [ $COMPARE -eq 1 ] ;
            then
                rm -f ${EACH_FILE}
            fi
        done
```

Found some similar problem but I dont know how to get it done
[List file using ls with a condition and process/grep files that only whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984665/list-file-using-ls-with-a-condition-and-process-grep-files-that-only-whitespaces)

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Does it have to be the filename that you use or can you be a little more fuzzy and use the modification,access or change time of the file? If so you can use `find` with the `delete` option. Something like `find . -type f -name '*.txt' -mtime +30 -print -delete` where +30 is 30 days or older

Comment: find command still take quite a lot of time unfortunately. Thanks for your solution anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in this thread. 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199554/get-files-with-a-name-containing-a-date-value-less-than-or-equal-to-a-given-inpu

The `awk` command is so powerful, only take me ~1 minute to deal with hundreds of thousand of files (1/10 compare to the loop).

```
ls | awk -v date="$DEL_DATE" '$0 <= date' | xargs rm -vrf
```

I can even count, copy, move with that command with the fastest answer I've ever seen.

```
COUNT="$(ls | awk -v date="${DEL_DATE}" '$0 <= target' | xargs rm -vrf | wc -l)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a refactoring which gets rid of the pesky `ls`.  Looping over a large directory is still going to be somewhat slow.

```
# Use lowercase for private variables
# to avoid clobbering a reserved system variable

# You can't have spaces around the equals sign
del_date="20180823"   

# No need for ls here
# No need for a temporary file
for filename in *[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
do
    # Avoid external process; use the shell's parameter substitution
    date=${filename%.txt}
    # This could fail if the file name contains literal shell metacharacters!
    date=${date#${date%?????????}}
    # Avoid expr
    if [ "$date" -lt "$del_date" ]; then
        # Just print the file name, null-terminated for xargs
        printf '%s\0' "$filename"
    fi
done |
# For efficiency, do batch delete
xargs -r0 rm
```

The wildcard expansion will still take a fair amount of time because the shell will sort the list of filenames. A better solution is probably to refactor this into a `find` command which avoids the sorting.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \( \
      -name '*1[89][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt' \
   -o -name '*201[0-7][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt' \
   -o -name '*20180[1-7][0-9][0-9].txt ' \
   -o -name '*201808[01][0-9].txt' \
   -o -name '*2018082[0-2].txt' \
 \) -delete
```

Comment: The loop is the reason it take lot of time. I tried everything with the loop. The solution with `find` command is better but quite complex. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
rm 201[0-7]*.txt            # remove all files from 2010-2017
rm 20180[1-4]*.txt          # remove all files from Jan-Apr 2018
# And so on
...
```

to remove a large number of files. Then your code would run faster.

Comment: Work really well with ~20k files, but [Argument list too long] for ~200k files. Awesome code btw.

Comment: Ok, can you then fine tune the command that has to deal with too many files. E.g. instead of `rm 20180[1-4]*.txt` can you use `rm 201801*.txt; rm 201802*.txt; ...`

Comment: maybe you forgot the condition but the original command is fine to delete file till the delete-date not the kind of rm 201801*.txt

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you give an example of what exactly does not work.

Anyway, you said you have ~200K files. Their file names differ in some way. E.g. if all 200K files were created in May 2018, then you could delete, everything created on May 1st, then May 2nd, and so on. This would progressively reduce the number of files you have.

Comment: I mean I want to delete all the file with the date in filename that smaller/before a exact given-date. So `rm 201801*.txt; rm 201802*.txt` only work on an exact day/month/year

Answer (score 0):

Yes it takes a lot of time if you have so many files in one folder.
It is bad idea to keep so many files in one folder.  Even simple ls or find will be killing storage. And if you have some scripts which iterate over your files, you are for sure killing storage. 
So after you wait for one hour to clean it. Take time and make better folders structure.  It is good idea to sort files according to years/month/days  ... possibly hours
e.g.

```
somefolder/2018/08/24/...files here
```

Then you can easily delete, move compress ... whole month or year.

Comment: Thank for your solution, but I have to deal with that huge data for the test, maybe not happen with real data.